# How do I enable SSL on my web site?

Tags: drupal, ssl, https

I have a website using drupal 7, pantheon (hosting), and nginx HTTP host.

I already have a certificate setup, but how do I actually make it so going to the site, ie, www.example.com, go to https://www.example.com?

Even if I manually type in , it still takes me to the HTTP.  I am new to this stuff and am trying to read but am having no luck.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Does your hosting company allow HTTPS connections?  Do they have to enable them for you, or do you have complete control over the HTTP server?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Drupal Stack Exchange](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. In particular, see [Configuring SSL](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/613/configuring-ssl).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have [registered your SSL](http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10694)

If you manage your own server (like you should do as a good little hacker!), you should tell your webserver to use SSL.

Basic: - make sure to tell apache to use SSL by adding this in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www.example.com.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www.example.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Furthermore you should try to redirect all links to use https (so users cannot login via http and no unsecure links show up)

For more info you can check [apache's documentation on ssl](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/)